# Accessing same index of embedded lists

Tags: python

I have an image coded as follows: `image[RGBchannel][y][x]`

I would like to access the `RGBchannel` triple for each index. This is the method I'm currently using. Is there a more efficient way to write it?

```
image = [[[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9], [10, 11, 12]], [[13,14,15], [16,17,18]]]

for y in range(len(image[0]):
    for x in range(len(image[0][0]):
        rgb = []
        for channel in range(len(image)):
            rgb.append(image[channel][y][x])
        print rgb
```

And output is:

```
[1, 7, 13]
[2, 8, 14]
[3, 9, 15]
[4, 10, 16]
[5, 11, 17]
[6, 12, 18]
```

Without importing any 3rd party libraries or importing any internal modules, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @zvone Feel free to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
image = [[[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9], [10, 11, 12]], [[13,14,15], [16,17,18]]]
result = [x for z in zip(*image) for x in zip(*z)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 7, 13), (2, 8, 14), (3, 9, 15), (4, 10, 16), (5, 11, 17), (6, 12, 18)]
```

Comment: I cannot import any modules, including pre-loaded modules.

Comment: @jdehesa maybe `[[*x] for t in zip(*image) for x in zip(*t)] `?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Yes thanks, that's the best non-itertools way chain :)

Comment: @Adam_G Right, I removed the chain from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar way with zipping twice.

```
image = [
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
    [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]],
    [[13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]],
]

image_TT = [[*x] for z in zip(*map(zip, *image)) for x in z]
# [[1, 7, 13], [4, 10, 16], [2, 8, 14], [5, 11, 17], [3, 9, 15], [6, 12, 18]]
in_order = image_TT[::2] + image_TT[1::2]
# [[1, 7, 13], [2, 8, 14], [3, 9, 15], [4, 10, 16], [5, 11, 17], [6, 12, 18]]
```